# Slack Webhook - returning invalid_payload

Tags: python, slack

I'm trying to send data to a slack webhook but I keep getting an invalid_payload response.

My results variable from below looks like this if i print it in my script:

{u'results': [{u'TunnelID': 11111}]}

```
webhook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/xxx/xxx'

response = requests.post(
    webhook_url, data=json.dumps(results),
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)

if response.status_code != 200:
    raise ValueError(
        'Request to slack returned an error %s, the response is:%s'
        % (response.status_code, response.text)
    )
```

I'm sure its a problem with the way my results variable is formatted, but I can't seem to find the right way to format it.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong. Please post the contents of the `results` variable. Also, you may want to set up a local web server and direct your request to it, just to see what comes out the other end. It's easier to debug if you see both ends of the connection

Comment: The contents of my "results" variable is : 

{u'results': [{u'TunnelID': 1111}]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to include `results` as the message itself? In which case, something like this?

```
response = requests.post(
    webhook_url, json={'text': str(results)},
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)
```