# Slack webhook returns invalid_payload when message is a url

Tags: webhooks, message, slack

I have:

```
def send_slack_message(message: str):
    payload = '{"text": "%s"}' % message
    response = requests.post(url,
                             data = payload)
    print(response.text)

def main(message_text: str):
    send_slack_message(message= message_text)
```

This fails with the error `invalid_payload`

```
main(message_text="""Found at \\something.co.uk\\blahblah\\blah""")
```

Is there documentation regarding what characters are permitted, as `\\` and `\` is failing in the message, but is required to send a link/windows path.

I looked at [Slack Webhook - Getting Invalid_Payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925395/slack-webhook-getting-invalid-payload) and [Slack Webhook - returning invalid_payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874125/slack-webhook-returning-invalid-payload), and neither answer my question

This works:

```
main(message_text = "some text")
```

Is there a way to format my message so it can send?

Answer (score 0):

It works when `\` is replaced with 4`\`, ie `\\\\`

```
main(message_text="""Found at \\\\somesite.co.uk\\\\blahblah\\\\blah""")
```